# SharePoint Get file content using path - Bad Gateway error

Tags: sharepoint, azure-blob-storage, power-automate

We are trying to upload files from SharePoint to Azure Blob storage in bulk via Power Automate cloud flow.

But, some of the files are errored out while downloading the file content from SharePoint:
[image: errored get content action]

Our flow fails with below error :

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 502,
    "source": "flow-apim-europe-002-northeurope-01.azure-apim.net",
    "clientRequestId": "9110fd61-0b21-45ff-86c9-f7a873c606f2",
    "message": "BadGateway",
    "innerError": {
      "status": 500,
      "message": "Attempt to reuse a disposed CobaltStream.\r\nclientRequestId: 9110fd61-0b21-45ff-86c9-f7a873c606f2\r\nserviceRequestId: 9110fd61-0b21-45ff-86c9-f7a873c606f2"
    }
  }
}
```

Failed once are valid files not corrupted which are of type .pptx, .xlsx, .doc, etc.

Also, when I try to run manually get file content by path in different POC flow passing same failed file path then it works. But not in loop I mean bulk.

[image: success get content action]

Thanks in advance!